# I have a problem which correlated with something

Tags: word-choice, ellipsis

- I have a problem which correlated with something.
- I have a problem which **is** correlated with something.

Can we omit 'is' in this case (like in the first sentence)?
Or is only the second sentence right?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences start with 'I have ...' indicating this is a current problem.  In that case either use the second sentence or:

- I **have** a problem which **correlates** with something.

If the problem is in the past, then you could use:

- I **had** a problem which **correlated** with something.

The first sentence mixes present and past tenses.